# What does "Non nasconderti lasciati conquistare" mean?

Tags: meaning, translation

Within the lyrics of the song *"Voulez Vous Danser"* by *"Ricchi e Poveri"*, there's a line that says:

> Non nasconderti lasciati conquistare

Does this mean **"Don't hide that I conquered you(r heart)"** or **"Don't hide that let you conquered you(r self)"** or anything else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are two phrases: Non nasconderti, lasciati conquistare. Don't hide, let yourself be (allow yourself to be) conquered.